# Regex - Match redundant sequences

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I would like to design a regexp that would capture all sequences of letters that are contained at least twice in a larger string :

For instance, let's take :

```
abzabuiabuz => a, b, ab, z, bu, u
```

I was thinking of lookaheads and lookbehinds but I can't see a proper solution.

Many thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

My original issue is to find `-a`, `-b` in `eu-a us-b eu-c eu-b us-a us-a`.

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: I am not using any particular language, I was just wondering if it could be possible to get this algorithm just with regex as I find them very elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture one or more characters and make a back-reference to those captured characters and then put the whole pattern inside a positive lookahead assertion.

```
(?=(.+).*\1)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jV2tO0/1)

Get the duplicated chars from the group index 1.

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/jV2tO0/2 or https://regex101.com/r/jV2tO0/3 ?

Comment: (-\w)(?=.*?\1) is almost fine but I still have 3 matches -a, -b, -a, whereas I would like them at most once, so rather -a, -b

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/yR1wN9/1):

```
\b\S+-(?:a|b)\b
```

It will match all words in your string ending in `-a` or `-b`.

```
eu-a
us-b
eu-b
us-a
us-a
```

In case you need to actually get just `-a`s and `-b`s, you can use `\b\S+(-(?:a|b))\b` regex and grab Group 1 values.